# Crear un subsitió de manera dinámica sin ingresar al código

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando algo que a lo mejor es muy complejo o no se puede hacer, llevo unos meses con php, pero no le encuentro la forma a esto (todo el sitio que he creado esta únicamente en la intranet de la empresa). Tengo un sitio en IIS donde tiene varios subsitíos con diferentes configuraciones y datos traídos de una BD. Estoy intentando crear de una manera dinámica, por medio de inputs la creación de subsitíos, poniendo únicamente los datos que cambiarían la info traída de la BD. Lo que tengo armado:

Un form que envía los datos a un PHP llamado crear_sitio.php

Tomo los POST del form, los meto en una variable a cada uno y luego los inserto en una tabla en MySQL:

```
$sitio = $_POST['sitio'];
$panel = $_POST['PanelName'];
$Titulo = $_POST['Titulo'];
$Reader1 = $_POST['Reader1'];
$Reader2 = $_POST['Reader2'];

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO datos_comedores (id, PanelName, Sitio, Titulo, 
 Reader1, Reader2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)"))
{
        $sitio = $_POST['sitio'];
        $panel = $_POST['PanelName'];
        $Titulo = $_POST['Titulo'];
        $Reader1 = $_POST['Reader1'];
        $Reader2 = $_POST['Reader2'];
            
      $stmt->bind_param("isssss",$id, $panel, $sitio, $Titulo, $Reader1, $Reader2);
        $stmt->execute();
}
```

En el mismo archivo, tomando un dato de los inputs para el nombre, creo la carpeta del subsitió y dentro de el todos los archivos PHP y JS (son 11 archivos que crea) que necesita el subsitió. Como aclaro arriba, los subsitíos son todos iguales a diferencia de algunos datos para la extracción de datos de la BD y que cada subsitió muestre lo que se le pide.

para la creación de los archivos utilizo:

```
 $dire = $_POST['sitio'];
 $archivo = fopen("$dire/index.php", "w+b");

if( $archivo == false ){
  echo "Error al crear el archivo";
} else{

  fwrite($archivo, "//TODO EL CONTENIDO INDEX.PHP");

 fclose($archivo);
```

Todo funciona muy lindo, me crea el subsitió, con los 11 archivos que hacen que funcione el mismo, el gran problema... Yo envió los datos "importantes" que son los inputs por POST y luego inserto en la BD. Tengo 7 subsitíos, pero no se como diferenciarlos sin tener que ir al código. Ya que una vez creado los archivos ejemplo Index.php uno de los datos "importantes" es el titulo:

```
<h1 class=\"p-titulo\"><?php 
            $traerDatos = "SELECT * FROM datos_comedores WHERE Sitio = $sitio";

            $respuestaMySQL = mysqli_query( $conn,$traerDatos );

            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( \$respuestaMySQL ) ) {
                $row[1]; //sitio
                $row[2]; //panelName
                $row[3]; //Titulo
                $row[4]; //Reader1
                $row[5]; //Reader2
            
                echo $row[3];
            }?>
</h1>
```

El tema esta en que la variable $sitio no tiene nada en el index.php porque fue enviada por POST al php crear_sitio.php no se como diferenciar en el WHERE por $sitio que es un datos único como un ID. Todo esto se puede desde el código, pero la idea es no ingresar al código. Ya que los que administrarían esto, no tienen acceso al código.

Espero se logre entender algo. Estoy atento si se necesita mas info o código. Agradecer mucho si alguien puede guiarme y/o ayudarme.

Comment: Todo eso que no podes hacer, no deberia estar en un achivo de configuracion del sitio??? igual... suena raro lo que queres hacer.. un archivo de configuracion, una copia de los archivos, y listo el otro sitio... me parece que estas sobredimensionando un problema...